# How to terminate real time logging after it has been initiated with journalctl -f &

Tags: linux, bash, background-process, journalctl

**Environment:** CentOS 8

I turned on real time logging with the command,

```
$ journalctl -f &
```

I got the information I needed but unfortunately I'm not sure how to stop it.  `[CTRL] -c` does not stop it.

Is there a simple command to terminate live logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have started the `journalctl` process in the background (by using ampersand `&` at the end of the line), which means that it is executed independently of the shell from where you started it. Thus you can't stop the process by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

To stop all `journalctl` processes at once you could just enter

```
killall journalctl
```

This will stop all processes named `journalctl` that have been started with your system user.

If you are unsure if there are more processes with that name you could check this with grepping the process list for `journalctl`:

```
ps fax | grep journalctl
```

This will give you an output like this:

```
ps fax | grep journalctl
 2367 pts/7    S      0:00          |       \_ journalctl -f
 2371 pts/7    S+     0:00          |       \_ grep --color=auto journalctl
```

In this example the first entry would be the journalctl process, the second results from grepping the process list (which greps itself). The first column of the output shows the process id (pid). In order to stop one specific `journalctl` process just enter

```
kill 2367
```

Mind that you will have to have adequate permissions to stop that process. This means that if the process has been startet by a root user then you can only stop the process if your user also has root privilege, e.g. using `sudo` to execute the `killall` or `kill` command.

Comment: It might worth mentioning that until you exit the shell which started the `journalctl` process, you can query the background processes with the `jobs` command, and use `kill %jobid` to kill a specific background job.

Comment: @Lacek yes (and also `fg` and `bg`), provided you have these tools installed on your system (which is not default)

Comment: `jobs`, `fg`, and `bg` are bash builtins, not separate tools.